# How to install openrc init system in ubuntu?

Tags: boot, openrc

I have noticed `openrc` package after I have upgraded to 14.10.

So, is it possible to get rid of upstart and systemd(logind, udevd) and upstart and move to it?

I have installed the package and have `rc-*` commands, but `/sbin/init` is still upstart and systemd components are still there. I have tried to set `init=/sbin/openrc` but pc then failed to boot, printing something about deadlock resolving.

Comment: reopened - Seems like a reasonable question - its not a beta question per se - so is valid.

Comment: I don't have a guide, but: 1. From the [history](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/utopic/+source/openrc/0.12.4+20131230-9), this looks like it was pulled automatically from Debian `sid`, so it may not be supported in Ubuntu yet. 2. From the [Debian Wiki](https://wiki.debian.org/OpenRC), all talk is about `sysv-rc` (and from what I understand, it enhances sysv-style init instead of replacing it) so where old-school init scripts are used, OpenRC might be brought into play by Upstart, but init itself remains Upstart. (That's pure speculation, though.)

Comment: It seems quite true, although it looks like it was in Gentoo, here it is not a separate init system, as it is not going to work without upstart or systemd components already running.

Comment: Nope, even in Gentoo it was not a separate `init` system. The [wiki](http://wiki.gentoo.org/wiki/Comparison_of_init_systems) shows that 1. sysv-init is used by OpenRC, and 2. OpenRC does not run as a daemon (unlike sysv-init, upstart or systemd, which run as PID 1, like a true init). (Also, please tag me if you reply - since fossfreedom has commented here, this is thread now involves three people and only you will get notified automatically.)

Comment: @muru aha, I see now. It is the exact behavior I've been observing. OpenRC wrapped up the upstart, systemd components are seem to be used by the upstart, too. So, if I understand clearly, I get only one more set of commands and no benefits at all from this, and OpenRC is already installed correctly.

Comment: Migrated to gentoo with systemd

Comment: As of 2022 - and earlier - upstart has been removed from Ubuntu and the project mothballed, and OpenRC no longer appears to be available in Ubuntu repositories. There is also an openrc init program called (appropriately enough) `openrc-init`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem that the question holds the answer itself. As @muru pointed, openrc does not replace `/sbin/init`, but works in pair with the init system already running.

So the correct answer for ubuntu 14.10 and higher, is just `sudo apt-get install openrc`, reboot and see your system running a zoo of multiple init systems.

PS: After installation, boot time increased in about two times, and after removal, it just have removed half of the packages as well.